# Using LSTM to predict a simple synthetic time series. Why is it that bad?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I just started playing with LSTM in keras and I find the possibility of learning the behaviour of time series very fascinating.
I've read several tutorials and articles online, most of them showing *impressive* capabilities in predicting time series, so I gave it a go. The first thing that I noticed is that all the articles I've found always use the validation data in av very unfair way. My idea of *predicting a time series* is that I use the training data to build a model and use the last *N* elements of the training data to estimate the future behaviour of the series. To do that, the model has to use its own predictions as inputs to step forward in the future.

What I've seen people doing, instead, is to estimate the accuracy of the testing set at any time in the future, using the ground truth as input for the estimation. This is very unfair, because it does not produce a real prediction!

I tried to code my own LSTM prediction in Keras (please find the code below), and I started with a relatively simple case, a combination of a parabola and a sinusoid. Unfortuntely, results are quite unsatisfying. Here are a few examples, obtained by changing the parameters of the network:

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

[image: Example 3]

Do you have any suggestion to get better results? How can LSTM predict complex behaviours if they can't predict such a "simple" signal?

Thank you,
Alessandro

```
import os
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import keras

# Number of vectors to consider in the time window
look_back = 50
N_datapoints = 2000
train_split = 0.8

# Generate a time signal composed of a linear function and a sinusoid
t = np.linspace(0, 200, N_datapoints)
y = t**2 + np.sin(t*2)*1000
y -= y.mean()
y /= y.std()

plt.plot(y)

# Reshape the signal into fixed windows for training
def create_blocks(y, look_back=1):
    x_data, y_data = [], []
    for i in range(0, len(y)-look_back-1):
        x_data.append(y[i:i+look_back])
        y_data.append(y[i+look_back])
    return np.array(x_data), np.array(y_data)


x_data, y_data = create_blocks(y, look_back)

# Split data in training and testing
N_train = int(x_data.shape[0]*train_split)
x_train = x_data[:N_train, :, None]
y_train = y_data[:N_train, ]
x_test = x_data[N_train:-1, :, None]
y_test = y_data[N_train:-1:, ]

# Get the time vector for train and test (just to plot)
t_train = t[0:N_train-1, None]
t_test = t[N_train:-1, None]

# Network
from keras import Model, Input
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Activation, BatchNormalization, Dropout

inputs = Input(shape=(look_back, 1))
net = LSTM(32, return_sequences=False)(inputs)
net = Dense(32)(net)
net = Dropout(0.25)(net)
outputs = Dense(1)(net)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.rmsprop(), loss='mean_squared_error')

model.summary()

# Callback
from keras.callbacks import Callback
class PlotResuls(Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):
        self.fig = plt.figure()

    def save_data(self, x_test, y, look_back, t_test):
        self.x_test = x_test
        self.y = y
        self.t_test = t_test
        self.look_back = look_back

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        if epoch % 20 == 0:
            plt.clf()
            y_pred = self.x_test[0, ...]
            for i in range(len(x_test)+1):
                new_prediction = model.predict(y_pred[None, -self.look_back:, ])
                y_pred = np.concatenate((y_pred, new_prediction), axis=0)


            plt.plot(t, y, label='GT')
            plt.plot(self.t_test, y_pred, '.-', label='Predicted')
            plt.legend()
            plt.pause(0.01)
            plt.savefig('lstm_%d.png' % epoch)


plot_results = PlotResuls()
plot_results.save_data(x_test, y, look_back, t_test)

model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), epochs=100000, batch_size=32, callbacks=[plot_results])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already shown in Primusa's answer, it is helpful to allow the recurrent layer to output its hidden state using `return_sequences=True`, together with a `Bidirectional` layer which has been shown to better capture temporal patterns. Additionally, I would argue that you need to have some sort of an intuition towards the kind of function you're trying to approximate- trying to decompose it into a number of functions and constructing a sub-network for each usually speeds up the learning process, especially so when using appropriate activation combinations. Applying weight regularization is also relevant as it may stop the extreme divergence due to error accumulation. Note also that unless you use `stateful=True`, you will need to provide the network with a long enough time frame to inspect long-range patterns (i.e. the parabola is easy to approximate as a line if the time-window is small).

Concretely, the below alterations achieve a (still rapidly decreasing) MSE of (1.0223e-04/0.0015
) after 20 epochs and (2.8111e-05/3.0393e-04) after 100 epochs, with a lookback of 100 (note that I have also changed your optimizer to **Adam** which I simply prefer):

```
from keras import Model, Input
from keras.layers import (LSTM, Dense, Activation, BatchNormalization, 
                      Dropout, Bidirectional, Add)

inputs = Input(shape=(look_back, 1))

bd_seq = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True,
                            kernel_regularizer='l2'), 
                       merge_mode='sum')(inputs)
bd_sin = Bidirectional(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, 
                            kernel_regularizer='l2'), 
                       merge_mode='sum') (bd_seq)

bd_1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(1, activation='linear'), 
                     merge_mode='sum')(bd_seq)
bd_2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(1, activation='tanh'), 
                     merge_mode='sum')(bd_sin)
output = Add()([bd_1, bd_2])

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
```

[image: 20 epochs]

[image: 100 epochs]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm impressed by the fact that this configuration only works in the exact way you suggested it. If I remove the regularizer, or change merge_mode to 'concatenation', or swap the number of units between the "seq" and "sin" branches, results are terrible again...

Is there any side effect in using Bidirectional when using LSTM?

Comment: I also didn't really understand the structure you used. My naive approach of combining two sequences would be having two branches, with the same inputs, one for the sinusoid and one for the parabola, which I would simply add in the last layer. In your case, you have a branch which is a cascade of 3 LSTMs, and another which is a sequence of only 2 LSTMs. What is this inspired from?

Comment: The side-effect of a bidirectional layer is a two-fold parameter growth; 1) because you are essentially constructing a second, 'backwards' version of your layer, and 2) if you're (as you mentioned) not element-wise merging the two outputs (i.e. with addition or multiplication), you're vastly increasing the width of your layer which is then fed into subsequent layers. As for the number of units chosen for each layer, my intuition is that we want to capture patterns of varying complexity over varying time frames, therefore a single representation would not suffice.

Comment: It would be interesting to toy around with the layer stacking and also visualize the output of each top layer to see which pattern each one is learning. I am assuming that the tanh layer is the one learning the sinusoid while the linear is learning the parabola.

Comment: In general, it is important to keep in mind that you get exponentially more representational capacity through depth compared to width, so enhancing your networks with narrow, deep, task-specific layers is usually helpful.

Comment: That was very useful, thank you again! I tried doing a few more tests and I realized that with the right data structure, even the most stupid fully connected network achieves great performances. If I keep the data in the form of (lookback, 1), rather than (lookback, ) and then feed it into a dense(4,8,16,1), results are incredible and the training time is basically zero. And this is using no regularization, no activation function, nothing at all! I'm amazed by its simplicity

Comment: I wonder now if there's any synthetic function where LSTM shows its best, being impossible to be approximated by a simple fully connected network...

Comment: That's a good question; first of all, fully connected networks are proven to be able to approximate **any** function so the immediate answer is no. Practically, however, LSTM (being a recurrent network) is able to capture more complex, evolving processes far easier than a fully connected network.

Answer (score 2):

While neural networks are very complex and powerful, they aren't a magic box. Many times you need to fine-tune your networks in order to get better results.

I tweaked your model and I got these results:

[image]

While they are by no means extremely accurate, I would say they are much better than the results you have posted in your question. This neural network has a clear sense of the frequency of the wave, but needs a bit more work on determining the general trend of the line. You can see how its ability to predict worsened as it approached the max of the curve.

The model I used was:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(8, return_sequences=True),input_shape=(50, 1),))
model.add(LSTM(8, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(4, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

I shortened your look_back period from 100 to 50 to shorten the training time. I trained the model for fifty epochs on a batch size of 5:

```
c.fit(epochs=50, batch_size=5)
```

This took about 15 minutes on my laptop (trained on CPU not GPU).

The main trick that I used to boost its accuracy was the Bidirectional LSTM, which involves two LSTMS, one with the sequences fed in forwards and the other with the sequences fed in backwards. The idea of this is to use future data to understand the context of the curve.

Do note that the use of future data is only during training. During actual predictions only previous data is used to predict the next point, and I used your "rolling predictions" idea as well, where the predictions are later used as inputs.